# Server error after restart "memory or battery problem"

Tags: windows-server-2008, ibm-xseries

Our IBM server gives an error saying "memory or battery problem has been detected adapter has recovered but cached data was lost"  Please press any key to continue." and to press the key we have to travel miles to the data center.Is there any way to resolve this error.
It has a windows server 2008 r2 loaded in it.I'm a newbie.Please help 
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely your server has a battery-backed RAID controller installed and the battery for the controller is failing.  As @Janne said, your best bet would be to contact IBM under your hardware maintenance contract to have the battery replaced (though you may need to pay for this work as these batteries are often classed as consumable items).

You shouldn't ignore this message, particularly if this server runs Exchange or SQL Server, the battery and memory on the RAID controller are key to ensuring that all transactions are properly committed to the RAID array even in the event of a power failure or UPS failure.

Answer (score 1):

Contact IBM and ask them to repair the server.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there anyone at the data centre who you can contact to press the key for you?

Having said that you'll need to travel to the data centre anyway to replace the battery or faulty memory module.